# Name our chatroom

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Our chatroom should have a cool name, not just "Mythology".

Examples:

- Programmers.SE - The Whiteboard
- Codegolf.SE - The Nineteenth Byte
- Puzzling.SE - The Green Llama

Answer here with your suggestions; vote for the suggestions you like!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## The Pantheon

([courtesy @iyrin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21351584#21351584))

Comment: The reason I like this one is that it's pretty mythos-neutral - in English today, "pantheon" just means "a set of gods". Now, yes, of course "pantheon" comes from Greek, but every word has to come from some language, and we're not going to avoid that no matter how hard we try.

Comment: Since my dream of The Agora was shot down in flames, I support this suggestion all the way, unless we can find something even better.

Answer (score 4):

## [Mead hall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead_hall)

...chat is supposed to be the [third place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place), after all.

Answer (score 3):

Symposium? Again, Greco-centric, but...

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a symposion was originally a drinking party. That would make it a wink at the Meta.SE chatroom, "Tavern on the Meta". Voting up.

Answer (score 1):

## The Lost Temple

The temple because it is about mythology and the stories about gods. And "lost" because it is about the religions of the past. "Lost Temple" is a bit cliché, but it became a cliché because it appeals to people.

Answer (score 0):

People were saying either:

**AGORA**

**VALHALLA**

**RIVER STYX**

or my idea is:

**ATLANTIS**

or

**EL DORADO**

Answer (score -1):

**Myths of a lost age**

A bit more poetry than the Olympus!

Comment: Too wordy for a title.

Answer (score -2):

## Olympus

Yes, it's simple. Yes, everybody would think of that. But it's nice, because Olympus is were the councils took place and so seems cool to me.

Comment: I think this is too greek-specific